# Position Buttons in a Circle Around a Button

Tags: android, animation, geometry, absolute

I want to place some (a variable number of!) buttons in a circle around a button in the center. It should be flexible enough that I can easily add one button more in the circle or remove one.
I'd also maybe like to add some animation in the future: the buttons should appear from one side and then circle around the button in the center.

It would be extremely easy to implement but android somehow doesn't allow to set absolute positions.

I mean I can easily calculate the positions where the buttons should be on the circle but how can I the place them there?

By the way, I don't want to add the buttons dynamically they are already on the view (wie View.INVISIBLE).

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried `RelativeLayout` and setting left and top margin of the `View` during animation...?

Comment: This really does work. I was kind of hoping for a more elegant way but I suppose there isn't one...